# rails: resque worker log doesn't honor log_tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, resque

I have the following line in my config/environments/development.rb:

```
    config.log_tags = [lambda { |req| Time.now }]
```

which works perfectly for the rails log (it prepends every entry with a timestamp).

I'd like to have the same behaviour in my resque workers.
The output of

```
p Rails.application.config.log_tags
```

in a resque job's perform method shows me, that there is a proc in it:

```
[#<Proc:0x007ffb36c14920@/.../config/environments/development.rb:49 (lambda)>]
```

But still, the log entries don't have timestamps.
I'm running out of ideas on why this happens...

Answer (score 1):

Log tags are evaluated [once per request](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ffa9540fd361eb34c445568b66abf283b9e658f8/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb#L21) in Rack middleware (`Rails::Rack::Logger#call`). There is no Web request when Resque runs and so you see nothing.

To get what you want, you should add code similar to `Rails::Rack::Logger#compute_tags` to Resque as a [job hook](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/docs/HOOKS.md#job-hooks), e.g., in `before_perform`.