# Using tagged logging in rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

Tagged logging in Rails is a neat way to make logs more readable and useful. Unfortunately, the way tagged logging was designed to work in Rails was via Rack middleware: [tags are evaluated once per request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17868714/622495). This means that tagged logging is not available, for example, to rake tasks.

I am looking for a way to add tagged logging to rake. `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging` works with a block so that would typically mean having to wrap the entire of rake application execution for best results. Are there any good docs on the rake lifecycle or any example of these types of hooks you can think of? There is always reading the code...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? an example of the kind of logging from your rake tasks that you desire would be useful.

Comment: I would like whatever is configured in my Rails applications's `config.log_tags`to be shown with all log entries. These include process ID, thread ID, and some deployment-specific parameters such as cluster name, node type and node ID.